# ipython notebook - what are these checkpoint files?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to upload the notebook files (*.ipynb) to my repository so my colleagues will be able to edit them as well.

I saw these checkpoint files and googled about it a little (there's not so much information out there about it), I think they're related to the autosaving. I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to commit them as well.

Comment: This one has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421663/what-are-jupyter-notebook-checkpoint-files-for

It's not necessary to commit the checkpoint files, unless you want to enable your colleagues to restore to previously saved checkpoints. If you don't have the checkpoint file, the restoring to the last checkpoint will give a failure, and that's it, nothing too worrisome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should ipynb checkpoints be stored in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306017/should-ipynb-checkpoints-be-stored-in-git)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What are Jupyter Notebook checkpoint files for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421663/what-are-jupyter-notebook-checkpoint-files-for), which was asked two years later after this one received no answer. Despite the fact that the latter was asked after this one, it attracted many upvotes and quality answers, so it's this one which should be marked as duplicate.