# What are Jupyter Notebook checkpoint files for?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

Besides the original Jupyter Notebook file (`.ipynb` file), sometimes I get a checkpoint `.ipynb` file which seems to be directly linked to the original `.ipynb` file.

What's the purpose of these checkpoint files?

And what causes them to be generated (sometimes I get this sort of checkpoint file, and sometimes I don't)?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Jupyter creates a checkpoint file every single time you create an `.ipynb` file, and then it updates the checkpoint file every single time you *manually* save your progress for the initial `.ipynb`.

A manual save is what's done when the file is saved by clicking the *Save and Checkpoint* button:

[image: img]

Auto-saving, on the other hand, updates only the initial `.ipynb` file, not the checkpoint file.

When you revert from the initial `.ipynb` file to a previously saved checkpoint by using the *Revert to Checkpoint* button, the checkpoint file is what gets accessed and opened inside Jupyter.

[image: img2]

As a side note, the checkpoint file is located within a hidden folder named `.ipynb_checkpoints`. This folder is located within the same folder as the initial `.ipynb` file.

Comment: So this is essentially a simplistic version control? Very cool.

Comment: Yea, right, but as you said it, a *simplistic* one -- it only saves the last version of your work. And once you revert to the last version, you can't revert back to an even older version.

Comment: And I don't see any GUI way to get a diff, or an easy way to selectively pull content from the checkpoint.

Comment: For some thoughts about diffing, see `nbdime` and [Displaying Differences in Jupyter Notebooks – nbdime / nbdiff](https://blog.ouseful.info/2017/01/27/displaying-differences-in-jupyter-notebooks-nbdime-nbdiff/) and [Pondering a Jupyter Notebook “Diff”er Extension and Its Use as a Marking Tool – OUseful.Info, the blog…](https://blog.ouseful.info/2017/06/02/pondering-a-jupyter-notebook-differ-extension-and-its-use-as-a-marking-tool/)

Comment: Not version control, but a simple backup.