# Recovering the file ipynb python

Tags: python, algorithm

I was running a code in python, I was running it in SageMath 8.2 Notebook and unfortunately my PC did not support and closed the program, now it does not open it, it is blank, is there any possibility of recovering the file ipynb o my algorithm?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2ApBIAnAJ15Y3SSHzrkDvpg_rYJ1EYa/view?usp=sharing

I try open in SAGEMATH and show:

> Error reading ipynb file '2019-05-10-115719/proyecto 1.ipynb': file
>   '2019-05-10-115719/proyecto 1.ipynb' size (=94.581575MB) too large
>   (must be at most 50MB); try opening it in a Terminal with vim instead
>   or write to help@cocalc.com. Fix this to continue.

Comment: that file is opening in google colab , is there any more data present in that notebook apart from 21 cells?

Comment: What other dates would you need?                                                                           I can not open the file, the file closes the program and I have to force the pc

Comment: try this https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-2ApBIAnAJ15Y3SSHzrkDvpg_rYJ1EYa

Comment: oohh, this deleted a small part but thank you very much, I thought I had to do it again.. THANKS

Comment: just as advice for later, please create checkpoints for easy recovery https://stackoverflow.com/a/46422176/4320263